# Difference between 'in the wrong' and 'wrong'

Tags: difference, idioms

I'd like to know the difference between
**'You are in the wrong'** and **'You are wrong'.**

And even if they are different in meaning, can I just say 'You are wrong'? Is there much difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to disagree with the other existing answer. "Wrong" and "in the wrong" are very close in meaning, and in a lot of occasions they can be used interchangeably.

If you look up the idiomatic phrase "in the wrong" in a dictionary, among the definitions you are bound to see "wrong." For instance take a look [here](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+wrong):

The Free Dictionary defines "in the wrong" as

> wrong; morally or legally incorrect.

Example sentences:

> I am not in the wrong, you are. No, you are **in the wrong**.

Merriam Webster defines it as

> in the position or situation of being wrong

Example:

> We had an argument and each of us thinks that the other was **in the wrong**.

It is really a matter of style and/or sentence structure to go with either one. You might as well say

> I am not **wrong**.

or

> We had an argument and each of us thinks that the other was **wrong**.

Answer (score -1):

I am wrong (maybe I just said 2 = 2 equals 6): means I made a mistake.
I am in the wrong (maybe I just said something bad and untrue about another person): means I have sinned.

We are all wrong some of the time. None of us ever wishes to be in the wrong.

Comment: None of us ever wishes to be **wrong / in the wrong**. Are the meanings different?